# Runs as a macro on visual basic for windows application - Access Database

Tags: ms-access, vba

Ok I am trying to programmatically generate records for an access database, but it keeps displaying like a macro and the line of code in question shows up in red.
What am I doing wrong?

```
Sub arrayData()
Dim custnames() As Varient
Dim num As Integer, dbs As Database, InsertRecord As String
Dim CustId As Integer, num1 As Integer
Dim CustName As String
Set dbs = CurrentDb()
CustId = 0
For num1 = 0 To 9
CustId = CustId + 1
custnames = Array("Peter", "Mary", "Frank", "Ian", "Ron", "Natalie","Radhu", "Jat", "David")
num = Int((9 - 0 + 1) * Rnd + 0)
// ERROR OCCURS ON THE LINE BELOW.
InsertRecord = "insert into CUSTOMER(CustNo,CustFName)values("&"'"&CustId&"'"&","&"'"&CustName&"'"&")"
dbs.Execute InsertRecord
Debug.Print CustId; CustName
End Sub
```

EDIT: Added & after CustName

Comment: You're missing an & after `CustName`

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Try to write readable string concatenations. And, as CustId is numeric, no quotes:

```
InsertRecord = "insert into CUSTOMER (CustNo,CustFName) values (" & CustId & ",'" & CustName & "')"
```